# What is the meaning of the phrase "localizing the value of a function"?

Tags: fourier-analysis, terminology, harmonic-analysis

What does this Wikipedia quote mean: "In the context of harmonic analysis, a branch of mathematics, the uncertainty principle implies that one cannot at the same time localize the value of a function and its Fourier transform. "?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Harmonic_analysis

In particular what does the word "localize" in "localize the value of a function" mean?

If a function is $y=f(x)$, does localizing it's value mean finding the value of $x$ of the function, in other the words what I usually call the [argument of the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function)?

In Swedish we use the word "lokalisera" for "localize". This has the meaning "to find out where something is". So if I know the value of a function, then to localize would mean to tell where that value is. Since we already know what the value of the function is, its y-value, what is left to figure out is to find where at the x-axis the value is. Am I right?

Comment: There is more to be said than this, but I think localization usually means confining the support, roughly. For example, a localization of a function $f$ might mean considering $f \chi$ where $\chi$ is a smooth function with support in a given compact interval with desirable properties. Uncertainty says that $(f \chi)^{\wedge}$ does not have compact support, and so is not localized in frequency.

Comment: But there are probably more than one type of "localization" and different colloquial senses in which one uses this word. I will think about it more and try to come up with a more detailed answer. A general idea is that if one considers a family of localizations, say $f \chi_\alpha$, then one should be able to sum properties of the localizations to get a property of $f$. For example if $(\chi_\alpha)$ is a partition of unity, then $f = \sum f \chi_\alpha$.